# Grails json cells with enum

Tags: grails, groovy, enums, dns

In my code I have a domain object with an Enum type in it.  That enum type saves and retrieves fine from the database.  I am converting a list of domain objects into json cells.  All fields except the enum are either a string or a long.  When the json gets picked up 'on the other side' it displays [Object object] for the column, instead of the enum name or enum value.  Is there something on either the domain or json side that would help with this?  Code/example below

Domain Class

```
class MyDomain {
long id
long otherValue
MyEnum enu  //Nullable per constraints
//Mapping and constraints are not special. 
}
```

Enum

```
enum MyEnum {
ENUM1("Value1"),ENUM2("Value2")
//constructor ommitted
String myValue
String toString() { myValue }
```

Json cell creation

```
def jsonCells = domainList.collect
    {
        [cell: [
                it.id,
                it.otherValue,
                it.enu?.value
            ],
            id: it.id]
    }
```

it.enu?.value works.  However, is there somehow a better way to do this where I don't have to call the value every time and can rely on the object?  I would have assumed that overriding the toString method would have taken care of it, but apparently I was wrong.  I know it seems like a minor issue, but its easier to forget ".value", especially as the same enum will be used in many domain objects.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're simply putting it in a List when building the object, it will treat it as an Object unless you specifically do something else with it (like you're doing currently).

One alternative would be to use `it.enu as String` or something similar, but that still probably doesn't achieve what you're trying to achieve.

Another (maybe overengineered?) way would be to create a method on the domain itself that returns the value, and then use that method when building JSON:

```
class MyDomain {
    MyEnum enu

    def enuVal() {
        enu?.value
    }
}
```

with

```
def jsonCells = domainList.collect {
    [cell: [
        it.enuVal()
    ],
    ...]
```

As for me, I guess I'd just prefer to use `it.enu?.val` in the JSON. Write a test for your JSON-rendering methods and make sure the value is what you expect it to be, so that you don't forget.

Comment: That makes sense.  I might do that simply because most of us are java programmers just getting in to groovy/grails so remembering to call it.enuVal() would likely be easier than remembering to call it.enu?.value.  I would worry that we would call it.enu.value by accident, which would completely kill the data display :)

Comment: @Joseph - If you're always rendering the domain in the same way, another option would be to just create a method on the domain (e.g. `toJson()`) that returns the list of properties formatted as they need to be. But that depends on your requirements and usage, I guess.